# Clicking TreeView item to select not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, selection

I have a tree with a hierarchical data template

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}" >
   <TreeViewItem Focusable="True" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTipText}" >
      <TreeViewItem.Header>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Focusable="True" >
            <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0">
               <Image.Source>
                  <Binding 
                                Path="IsLeaf" Converter="{StaticResource cnvIsBooleanToStringArrayItemConverter}">
                     <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                        <x:Array Type="sys:String">
                           <sys:String>..\Images\document_plain.png</sys:String>
                           <sys:String>..\Images\folder.png</sys:String>
                        </x:Array>
                     </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                  </Binding>
               </Image.Source>
            </Image>
            <TextBlock MaxWidth="300" Text="{Binding Desc}" Focusable="True" />
         </StackPanel>
      </TreeViewItem.Header>
   </TreeViewItem>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I want to select an item by clicking at the TextBlock containing "Desc", but the only way to select an item is by clicking in the space left of the text (the image area)

Any clues what is missing?

Regards
Klaus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As H.B. says, you should not put a TreeViewItem inside your hierarchical data template, since WPF will automatically create one to wrap your content.

If you want to bind to the ToolTip, you can do it inside the ItemContainerStyle, which will apply to *all* your treeview items within the TreeView.

```
<TreeView .... your parameters >
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTipText}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

I hope this helps.

Although I haven't tested it, I think your hierarchical data template should look like this:

```
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}" >
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0">
                   <Image.Source>
                      <Binding Path="IsLeaf" Converter="{StaticResource cnvIsBooleanToStringArrayItemConverter}">
                         <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                            <x:Array Type="sys:String">
                               <sys:String>..\Images\document_plain.png</sys:String>
                               <sys:String>..\Images\folder.png</sys:String>
                            </x:Array>
                         </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                      </Binding>
                   </Image.Source>
                </Image>
                <TextBlock MaxWidth="300" Text="{Binding Desc}"/>
             </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 7):

Your data template specifies a `TreeViewItem` at its root, but the TreeView will automatically create a TreeViewItem around your template, having a TreeViewItem in a TreeViewItem confuses the selection mechanism.

Do something like this:

```
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTipText}"/>
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Header">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        ...
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

**Edit:**
After some testing it turns out that messing with the container is quite troublesome, i did not get it display the tooltip that way, unless you found a way to do it i recommend you stick to only setting `HierarchicalDataTemplate.VisualTree` (the default content of HierarchicalDataTemplate) which will be placed in the header of the auto-generated TreeViewItem.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the Background="Transparent" on the StackPanel and/or remove the Focusable setting on the TextBlock.